# Comparing a string array index to a string

Tags: java, arrays, string

I'm having trouble comparing an array that holds a word that's broken up into letters. Here is my code: (it's part of a hangman game)

```
public static void isGuessCorrect( String guess, String wordInPlay, String[] hangmanScores){

    String[] letterGuessedAgainst = wordInPlay.split(""); 

    for (int i = 0;i < letterGuessedAgainst.length; i ++)
        System.out.print(letterGuessedAgainst[i]);

    System.out.println("Letter guessed against is: "+letterGuessedAgainst[1]);//testing purposes
    System.out.println("My guess is: "+guess.charAt(0));//testing purposes

    for (int i = 0;i < letterGuessedAgainst.length; i++){
        if (letterGuessedAgainst.equals(guess.charAt(0))){//this line isn't working
            System.out.println("they're equal");//want it to return this
        }//end if
        else
            System.out.println("they're not");//returns this instead
    }//end for
}//end method
```

- `guess` is a String
- `holds` a letter
- `wordInPlay` is the word that is in play
- `letterGuessedAgainst` is the letter of the word that is being played
- `hangmanScores` is an array that only holds "_", corresponding to the number of letters in the word

Any help would be immensely appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: What about that line isn't working? Are you getting a compilation error? Or is the output not what you expect?

Comment: You need to specify what you would like help with. A general "help me" does not do us any good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated your code to start working:

```
    public static void isGuessCorrect(String guess, String wordInPlay, String[] hangmanScores) {

    char[] letterGuessedAgainst = wordInPlay.toCharArray(); //Changed to Char Array

    for (int i = 0; i < letterGuessedAgainst.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(letterGuessedAgainst[i]);
    }

    System.out.println("Letter guessed against is: " + letterGuessedAgainst[1]);//testing purposes
    System.out.println("My guess is: " + guess.charAt(0));//testing purposes

    for (int i = 0; i < letterGuessedAgainst.length; i++) {
        if (letterGuessedAgainst[i] == guess.charAt(0)) {//Made == since they are all Chars now
            //System.out.println("Nice guess! Here are all the "+guess+"'s in the word.");
            //System.out.println(hangmanScores);
            System.out.println("they're equal");//want it to return this
        }//end if
        else {
            System.out.println("they're not");//returns this instead
        }
    }//end for
}//end method
```

There is likely other places that can be improved but this fixes your direct problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `letterGuessedAgainst` is an array and you are trying to compare a `String[]` vs `char`

```
 if (letterGuessedAgainst.equals(guess.charAt(0))){//this line isn't working
```

First of all, you have to use the index `i` in the loop

```
letterGuessedAgainst[i]
```

Secondly, you need to compare against `guess` and not `guess.charAt(0)` since you will not be able to do `equals()` when comparing `String` and `char`

Since you already defined that `guess` is a String the contains only 1 character then you could do:

```
if (letterGuessedAgainst[i].equals(guess)) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't you need to do

```
if (letterGuessedAgainst[i].charAt(0).equals(guess.charAt(0))){
```

instead of comparing an array to a char

Answer (score 0):

Rather then splitting into a number of single character `String`(s), I suggest you use `wordInPlay.toCharArray();` then you could iterate that `char[]` with a [`For-Each` loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) (and I believe you wanted to either search the entire `String` and say the character was found or not; not whether each individual character matches) and your code might look something like

```
public static void isGuessCorrect(String guess, String wordInPlay,
        String[] hangmanScores) {
    char[] letterGuessedAgainst = wordInPlay.toCharArray();
    char ch = guess.charAt(0);
    System.out.println("My guess is: " + ch);
    boolean found = false;
    for (char letter : letterGuessedAgainst) {
        if (letter == ch) {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (found) {
        System.out.printf("%s contains guess %c%n", wordInPlay, ch);
    } else {
        System.out.printf("%s does not contain guess %c%n", wordInPlay, ch);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing a char (which charAt() returns) to a string, which they are not equal. I would suggest using either character arrays, or also using charAt() on letterGuessedAgainst.

Source:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (guess.length==0) return null; // some kind of error handling
 char quessedChar = guess.charAt(0);
 for (int i = 0;i < letterGuessedAgainst.length; i++){
        if (letterGuessedAgainst.charAt(i) == quessedChar ){
            //System.out.println("Nice guess! Here are all the "+guess+"'s in the word.");
            //System.out.println(hangmanScores);
            System.out.println("they're equal");//want it to return this
        }//end if
        else
            System.out.println("they're not");//returns this instead
    }//end for
```

- I would suggest at first place some code to validate your input data. You will fail if you will pass an empty string for guess.
- Secondly you are comparing String with a character. Use above code.